# Define multiple environment variables for debug in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, environment-variables

I want to debug a program in Visual C++ that depends on two environment variables.

I know how to define one variable (*Properties* → *Configuration Properties* → *Debug* → *Environment*), but I am having problems defining two variables. 
I have tried to separate them with `\` and `|`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my VS Express 2012, there's a down arrow that when you click on it shows the alternative `<Edit...>`. If you select it you will get a dialog with a text entry box. This text entry allows multiple lines. Simply define one variable per line.

Note that it will look weird in the single-line text box in the project property dialog.

Comment: This does NOT work in the German version of VS2010. This is an unfixed Microsoft bug - see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727324/msvs10-c-deu-debugger-environment-variables-missing-linefeed